# Sum an Array - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sum

I'm just starting out and I'm looking for an easy way to sum a simple array. I've read into apple developer site on key value coding and I don't understand how to apply that to my array or if that's the appropriate way to sum this.

My stumbling block with the key value coding is the .keypathToProperty - I can sort of understand that you need a further reference in a 2D array but they don't show the array code, only the keypath to the title of the row so I can't figure it out yet.

```
NSMutableArray *numArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    [numArray addObject:num1];
    [numArray addObject:num2];  
    [numArray addObject:num3];
    [numArray addObject:num4];
```

I appreciate the replies!

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The automatic way to do it is:

```
NSNumber * sum = [numArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

But if you're just starting out, I would recommend avoiding the collection key-path operators and go for the more simple way:

```
double sum = 0;
for (NSNumber * n in numArray) {
  sum += [n doubleValue];
}
```

Comment: Jeez, I did not know about `@sum.self`, wow, every day I am reminded of how much I don't know.

Comment: Interestingly there are such key also like "max.self", "min.self"...
Awesome solution..

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**: ([Dave DeLong's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643787/499581) transformed):

```
let sum = (numArray as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath:"@sum.self") as! Double
```

This should work in a similar fashion to it's Objective-C counterpart.

Comment: I know you're doing it as an example of using keypaths, but for any newer Swift readers, you might want to use a reduce instead!

    `let sum = numArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }`

Comment: @MikeSprague: I'm not disagreeing with you on which might be more appropriate, although I'm interested in your reasoning why an alternative method shouldn't be presented. The reason I like this method is that for the amount of code involved it works quite well for an array which contains mixed integers and string values.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 4:

```
let array = [1,2,3,5]
let sum = array.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
print(sum)
```

Comment: This is an Objective-C question.